# How to hide VS Code Integrated Terminal tab popup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, popup, integrated-terminal-window

I find the popup in the VS Code integrated terminal menu tree to be annoying. Is there a way to turn this off?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te9Bf.png)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open VS Code.
2. Open at least two integrated terminals in VS Code.
3. In the integrated terminal menu tree, hover over one of the entries.
4. A popup display that shows some information about the process that is running the integrated terminal.

Desired result:

1. Open VS Code.
2. Open at least two integrated terminals in VS Code.
3. In the integrated terminal menu tree, hover over one of the entries.
4. No popup is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect if there was a setting to control this, it'd be prefixed by `terminal.integrated.tabs.`. And there is no such setting with such a prefix.

I think related source code is in [src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalTabsList.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalTabsList.ts) (not 100% sure).

As a really stupid workaround, you could disable tabs altogether and just have the dropdown instead: `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false,`.